# Is scalebase nosql database or not?

Tags: sql, scalebase, nosql

I have read about [scalebase](https://www.scalebase.com/the-story-of-newsql/) but did not understand is it NoSQL database or not? Or they just well horizontal scaled SQL database?

Comment: No, it's based on MySQL and thus is a **relational** DBMS - not a "NoSQL" product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ScaleBase) it is a distributed MySQL implementation. It supports SQL. So, by definition, it doesn't qualify as "NoSQL"